# Find last column and last row in non-contiguous range

Tags: vba, excel

I want to quickly be able to find the right most column and last row of a non contiguous range of data without using  `UsedRange`. I have not found a quicker way than this method out there. Any ideas?

```
Function Range_Find_Method(ws As Worksheet)
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long

With ws
    lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=.Range("A1"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row

    lCol = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=.Range("A1"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Column
End With

Debug.Print lRow
Debug.Print lCol

end function
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at the following[Ron De Bruin LastRow, LastColumn](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm)

Comment: @QHarr - my idea as well :)

Comment: @Vityata Yes. Always looking at his stuff.  I've never considered it in terms of which is quicker but rather which suits the layout of my data (which in turn might impact which is quickest (shortest path kind of thing)).

Comment: @QHarr - I knew the code was either from there or from CPearson.

Comment: @QHarr , thank you for the prompt response! Adding it to my repertoire.

Comment: @Luuklag - Interesting! I knew that UsedRange shouldn't be used, but never knew *why* . Thanks